# jQuery: open file upload window after click on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, file-upload

I use (Css 2.1 And Jquery) to style file inputs

It Work Fine And every thing work fine to now

Here's example i'm talking about

[Input File Demo](http://www.shbkat.com/careers.html)

If you are using Firefox Every thing Work fine

But when Using Chrome  **Can't select file from first time** `My Problem`

To select file in this demo Its Beside **Cv**

Here's My JQuery Code

```
(function($){
              $.fn.SafyForm = function(){
                   $(".safy_input_file").live("click", function(){
                                     var obj = $(this) ;
                                     obj.prev("input[type=file]").click() ;
                                     obj.prev("input[type=file]").change(function(){
                                         var txt = $(this).val();
                                         obj.children("span").text(txt) ;
                                     });
                   }) ;
                   return this.each(function(){
                         if($(this).is("input[type=file]"))
                                {
                                  $(this).hide().after('<div class="safy_input_file"><span> [ .docx & .doc & .pdf & .rar ] </span><label>اختار ملف</label></div>')
                                }
                   }) ;
              }
        })(jQuery);

        $(document).ready(function(){
              $('input[type=file]').SafyForm() ;
        }) ;
```

**Code After update**

```
(function($){
              $.fn.SafyForm = function(){
                   $(".safy_input_file").live("click",function(){
                                     var obj = $(this) ;
                                     obj.prev("input[type=file]").click() ;

                   }) ;

                   $("input[type=file]").change(function(){
                            var txt = $(this).val();
                            var safyobj = $(this).next('.safy_input_file') ;
                            safyobj.children("span").text(txt) ;
                   });

                   return this.each(function(){
                         if($(this).is("input[type=file]"))
                                {
                                  $(this).hide().after('<div class="safy_input_file"><span> [ .docx & .doc & .pdf & .rar ] </span><label>اختار ملف</label></div>')
                                }
                   }) ;
              }
        })(jQuery);

        $(document).ready(function(){
              $('input[type=file]').SafyForm() ;
        }) ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you right, in chrome twice run upload.
I tested your plugin in fiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/EPxkh/61/

and is correct(1 time run).
problem must be in other your webpage elements or scripts.

also try change:

> input[type=file]

to

> :file

Comment: Thank you @EmRa228 , yes i think the problem is in other events in js file ,  it work fine on chrome and ie with this update ( attached with question )

Comment: @MonaAbdelmajeed your arabic website has nice graphic design and best codes. I am from IRAN.
حظا سعيدا يا صديقي المصري

Comment: حظا سعيدا  لك ايضا :)   شكرا لك